# Specifying array size with constructor

Tags: java, arrays, object, variables

I found some answers on this but I probably didn't understand it correctly because it didn't work for me

`Employee` is an object defined in another class

```
public class Firm {
    Employee employees[];

    public Firm (int rosterSize){
        this.employees = new employees[rosterSize];
    }
}
```

> Error: cannot find symbol, class employees

**My question:** how can I specify the size of the array employees with a constructor?

Comment: If your class name is `Employee`, it should be `new Employee[rosterSize]`

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please tell us more about the error that you are getting as your quellcode looks OK. Cheers :)

Comment: what's the question, I failed to understand, could you pleas elaborate?

Comment: `Employee employees[];` makes no sense... Should be `Employee[] employees;` that is an array of `Employee` instances in a variable named `employees`...

Comment: @UsagiMiyamoto yeah, that's the idea. I want an array of Employee instances in a variable named employees. Problem solved, thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need create `Employee` array, try this:

```
this.employees = new Employee[rosterSize];
```

Comment: I thought I tried that already but I must have made a typo before. case solved thanks.

Answer (score 3):

```
public Firm (int rosterSize){
    this.employees = new Employee[rosterSize]; // the class name is what you need
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Thats simple. It has to be Object Name not its variable Name.

```
public class Firm {
    Employee employees[];

    public Firm (int rosterSize){
        this.employees = new Employee[rosterSize]; 
    }
}
```